# Yii & Yii2: how to configure routing on a single method with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I decided to move the logic with YII on Yii2 and a problem with the routing entry.

```
//yii1
'image/<id:\d+>*'   => array('image/get'),
```

But it doesn't work on YII2

```
//yii2 
'image/<id:\d+>*'   => 'image/get',
```

How to write the route to get function takes a variable number of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'image'   => 'image/get',
```

And in the ImageController get the params the normal way

```
$id = \Yii::$app->request->post('id');
```

I have defined

```
'my-account' => 'my-account/index',
```

The link /my-account?id=5&foo=bar works just fine.

Comment: I tried to do as you wrote above, but got the following error:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "image/4"